# Outlook 2013 script to save attachments then move email to folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I need a simple script for Outlook 2013 for a mailbox that customers send documents too.
I'm going to set a rule that that applies to all incoming mail. If the email has an attachment, it needs to be save to a folder. Then the mail, that the attachment was saved from, needs to be moved to a completed folder.

I think this is really simple, but I don't know much about VBA or Outlook scripting. I found this script, which removes the attachment and adds a date to the saved file, which is perfect.
I just need it to then move the completed email to a folder.
hopefully someone can help out.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")
    saveFolder = "\\myfilepath\"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683(v=office.15).aspx)method of the MailItem class can be used to get the job done.